# PowerBI DAX result is different from SQL result with the same logic when filtering early dates

Tags: sql, date, powerbi, dax

I have a measure in PowerBI that filtering records based on a date field earlier than 2009.
The code variables were renamed for readability.

```
myMeasure = 
    CALCULATE(  
        DISTINCTCOUNT('myFactTable'[RecordID])
        , FILTER(
            All('myFactTable'),
            'myFactTable'[myDatefield] < DATEVALUE("01/01/2009")
        )        
    )
```

The result of the measure as shown in a card visual is **62**

I used the following SQL query on the same data source assuming it will return identical results:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) OldrecordsCount
FROM 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        RecordID
    FROM 
        myFactTable
    WHERE
        myDatefield < '2009-01-01'          
) tbl1
```

But not as expected the result was **2**

Does the SQL query equivalent to the dax one?
Probably not, What could be the reason? Does PowerBI treats old dates differntly?
What do I miss?

When using the same query but reversing the conditions to `myDatefield > '2009-01-01'` and `'myFactTable'[myDatefield] > DATEVALUE("01/01/2009")` the results were both the same value, **2034**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any **blanks** within `myDatefield`, `DAX` will return `TRUE` for the comparison

```
myDatefield < DATEVALUE("01/01/2009")
```

Hence you should include an additional statement to check for non-blanks, e.g.:

```
=
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT( 'myFactTable'[RecordID] ),
    FILTER(
        ALL( 'myFactTable' ),
        'myFactTable'[myDatefield] < DATEVALUE( "01/01/2009" )
            && NOT ( ISBLANK( 'myFactTable'[myDatefield] ) )
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks. Had no idea that DAX include blanks in the count. Your code result was 2 as expected.

Answer (score 0):

get query :

```
SELECT count(*) as OldrecordsCount,
        RecordID
    FROM 
        myFactTable
    WHERE
        myDatefield < '2009-01-01' 
group by RecordID
```

write the result here

Comment: The result was two rows with count for each row

Comment: If there are empty lines in the field, then it's probably in them. Use DAX to filter empty values

Comment: Because in the database the filter works strictly according to the selection condition. This means that the search characters <> will skip empty values. And, the count aggregator doesn't count Null. But, dax , these facts don't work with dax. Thanks for your attention.